# What happens to an opened ofstream object if you kill the program from the terminal?

Tags: c++

First of all, I'm using a Shell Terminal, so I kill programs by Ctrl-C. Supose I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (){

  ofstream ofs("testing.txt");

  for (unsigned int i=0;;i++){
    ofs << i << endl;
  }
}
```

This program will save every natural number in a file until I kill it. My question is: The destructor of fstream is called when the program is killed or I'll have a corrupted file or somethimg like that?. Take in mind that I will use the file again in the future.

Comment: If the program is killed, nothing will run. What happens to the file is up to your operating system.

Comment: I use Ubuntu. So, if the program is running and I stop it (sorry for my English), the file will be usable depending on the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you use interrupt (`Ctrl-C`) and in the general case:

> ...an interrupt is a signal to the processor emitted by hardware or software indicating an event that needs immediate attention. An interrupt alerts the processor to a high-priority condition requiring the interruption of the current code the processor is executing. The processor responds by suspending its current activities, **saving its state**, and executing a function called an interrupt handler (or an interrupt service routine, ISR) to deal with the event...

What will happen to your output stream is system-specific and it depends if some caching is going on.